# Why won't my search bar and its functionality be displayed/work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I'm making a search bar that allows the user to filter the name of the place that they're looking for as they're typing it making it easier (by narrowing down the selection) for them in order to choose their desired choice.

But for some reason, I'm getting the error in the browser below.

What am I doing wrong in my code & how can I fix it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

let places = [
    {
        name: "something",
        location: "somewhere"
    },

    {
        name: "something2",
        location: "somewhere3"
    },

    {
        name: "something3",
        location: "somewhere4"
    },
];

class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchString: "",
            places: []
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            places: places
        });
        this.ref.search.focus();
    }

    handleChange() {
        this.setState({
           searchString: this.refs.search.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        let _places = this.state.places;
        let search = this.state.searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

        if(search.length > 0) {
            _places = _places.filter(function(places) {
                return places.name.toLowerCase().match(search);
            });
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.searchString}
                    ref="search"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />

                {
                    places.map(l => {
                        return(
                            <li>
                                {l.name} {l.location}
                            </li>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Error on the browser:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

  38 |     this.setState({
  39 |         places: places
  40 |     });
> 41 |     this.ref.search.focus();
  42 | }
  43 | 
  44 | handleChange() {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using string refs, the ref is available inside an object named `refs` and not `ref` and hence you should access it like `this.refs.search.focus();`

However having said that, you must make use of either [`React.createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref) if you are on version 16.3.0 or react or above or else use [`callback refs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)

Using createRef

```
class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchString: "",
            places: []
        };
        this.search = React.createRef();
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            places: places
        });
        this.search.current.focus();
    }

    handleChange() {
        this.setState({
           searchString: this.search.current.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        let _places = this.state.places;
        let search = this.state.searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

        if(search.length > 0) {
            _places = _places.filter(function(places) {
                return places.name.toLowerCase().match(search);
            });
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.searchString}
                    ref={this.search}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />

                {
                    places.map(l => {
                        return(
                            <li>
                                {l.name} {l.location}
                            </li>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Using callback refs

```
class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchString: "",
            places: []
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            places: places
        });
        this.search.focus();
    }

    handleChange() {
        this.setState({
           searchString: this.search.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        let _places = this.state.places;
        let search = this.state.searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

        if(search.length > 0) {
            _places = _places.filter(function(places) {
                return places.name.toLowerCase().match(search);
            });
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.searchString}
                    ref={(ref) => this.search = ref}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />

                {
                    places.map(l => {
                        return(
                            <li>
                                {l.name} {l.location}
                            </li>
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```